# IOS reorganize graphics on rotation

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, orientation

I'm making an iPad application with 19 buttons which are alle graphics. They are aligned next to and underneath eatchother, like in a grid. In portrait mode they are displayed nicely (because that's how I've set them) but I don't know what settings I need to choose for landscape mode.

When the device turns to landscape I've got room for 4 columns in stead of 3 in portrait for instance.
How can I make the app automatically adjust they layout of the buttons when rotated?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In iOS5.1 or older, you will need to do this in code. In iOS6, its possible you can use a UICollectionView - not sure haven't played with it.